# When doing a git clone --mirror where are the actual files?

Tags: git, git-clone, mirror

I have a project on github which I'd like to mirror on my server.

I've tried the following: `git clone --mirror git@github.com:user/repo.git`.

Then in the `repo.git` directory, I have the following file structure (eg, output of `ls`):

`FETCH_HEAD branches/ description info/ packed-refs HEAD config hooks/ objects/ refs/`

So my question is: **where are my files!?** It looks like there's a bunch of git related stuff, but I just can't find the code I've written. Am I missing something obvious?

Btw, `git status` returns `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree` but `git branch` returns the branches. Weird.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you `git clone --mirror`, it produces a bare repository, so it won't have a work area. I use `--mirror` more often to make a read-only clone of my working repo for others to pull from.

It sounds like you probably should just omit the `--mirror` option.

From [the `git clone` man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html):

> `--mirror`
>   Set up a mirror of the source repository. This implies `--bare`. Compared to `--bare`, `--mirror` not only maps local branches of the source to local branches of the target, it maps all refs (including remote-tracking branches, notes etc.) and sets up a refspec configuration such that all these refs are overwritten by a git remote update in the target repository.

To be fully clear, the bare, mirror repo does have the entire content of the repository that it was cloned from, but it does not have a work area where you can see these files. If you cloned from your mirrored clone (`git clone /path/to/local/mirror_repo.git`), you would get the work tree in that new, non-bare repo.

Comment: I didn't realise that bare repo didn't have work area. I'm probably not familier enough with git intricacies to understand this part of the doc correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, a bare repo is very close to being only what is inside the .git directory for a normal repo.

Comment: This is curious, is there not a way to pull everything down ? The full mirror history and the codebase with work tree?

Comment: @eddyizm "everything" is in the `.git` folder of the work area on a normal clone. You would have to go out of your way to do something different from the norm such as a shallow clone. Try executing `git log` to see the history or `git branch -a` to see all local and remote branches.